# Sick of nocaptcha recaptcha not working

Tags: support, captcha

I went on to https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Wanted to see what the highest voted answers are. So went here.
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer

SE says it wants to confirm if I am human. No probs. 
Loads the nocaptcha recaptcha and displays some really blurry images which I had hard time to pick the right ones and I come to below part.

[image]

Does this mean I got the captcha right?

If yes, what should I do after pasting the code into the box? Should I wait on the page for sometime? Or press enter? Or press a button somewhere?

This is the first time ever I had really bad experience on a SE site. Can't we have a choice of captcha we would like to fill up?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505540/elusive-recaptcha-bug-copy-code-always-fails

Comment: Also, here is another one: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/VJOkHGRXqlk Look at the 4th answer.

Comment: Temp solution until this gets fixed: [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet): `javascript:(function(f){document.getElementById(f).submit();})('nocaptcha-form');` (sorry, no simple link, the comment-editor does not seem to accept bookmarklet-urls). I solve the recatcha, copy the text and execute the bookmarklet, done. Probably a button should appear or a auto-submit using some fancy js (exotic methods) that fails to work for what ever reason. I'm having the same problem (consistently, for months), I haven't investigated further as my first attempt to a solution worked.